# When a SQL job starts, what is the value of @@ROWCOUNT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, jobs, rowcount

I have been looking for an answer to this question, but I believe it may be a useful piece of information for others as well.

I am working with TSQL in SQL server management studio. Due to the way our system processes information, it's desirable to do updates in smaller batches. A trick we use is to wrap updates in a while loop as such:

```
while (@@Rowcount <> 0)
begin
    update top (800) etc etc
end
```

I have created a job to do this update regularly and while this works in a query window, it does not seem to work in a job. Is the rowcount value populated when a job begins?

Comment: If you want to initiate the `@@ROWCOUNT` to be not 0, add `SELECT 1;` right before the loop.

Comment: Zero as the initial value for @@ROWCOUNT makes sense to me. I assume the reason why it works in SQL Server Management Studio is because Management Studio issues a bunch of commands on the same connection before executing what was entered in the query window. Of course fixing it should be straight forward, just SELECT some constant as DVT suggested.

Comment: `WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN; UPDATE ...; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK; END`. Because `@@ROWCOUNT` resets when you fart (metaphorically) it's best to use it only immediately after a statement and never before any you didn't issue. Incidentally, the `WHILE 1 = 1 ... BREAK` construct also works well when you use cursors (to avoid repeating the `FETCH` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is 0 at the beginning of a statement, what is happening for you is that when SSMS first opens up a connection it executes a series of queries behind the scenes (you can capture the specific queries with a trace), so you get a residual value for `@@ROWCOUNT` of 1.

When doing batch updates like this, I tend to take a slightly different approach:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE  TOP (100) ....
    SET     ...


    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;
END
```

I don't think this has any benefit whatsoever over doing something like:

```
SELECT 1;
WHILE  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

And is more long winded, but doing a pointless select or assignment just feels odd to me, perhaps owing to some minor OCD.

Comment: I like these answers, and I do like using breaks in otherwise perpetual loops.I did notice, though, when trying the print go print query that I could remove the go and get the same results and that putting a go between a select and the print doesn't seem to affect the rowcount though, so that may be inaccurate, or may not be how SQL studio handles it.

Comment: You are indeed correct, using `PRINT` will set `@@ROWCOUNT` to 0. So what I have said about a new batch resetting it is nonsense. I have removed that.

Answer (score 0):

`@@Rowcount` is system function with output `INT NOT NULL` --> `default value for int is 0`

You can get it by:

```
if @@rowcount = 0
    print 1
else 
    print 0
```

But don't try `select @@rowcount` at first row it's statements that make a simple assignment and is always set the @@ROWCOUNT value to 1. **:)**

So solution is add `select 0` before your `while`. It works because `@@rowcount` of `select 0` is one row..

```
select 0
while (@@Rowcount <> 0)
begin
    update top (800) etc etc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the value of `@@RowCount` in a variable allows you to avoid any assumption about the initial value and any problems with losing the value when another statement is executed.

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample Int );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 5 );

declare @RowCount as Int;
-- If there is any work to do then initialize   @RowCount   to   1 , otherwise   0 .
set @RowCount = case when exists ( select 42 from @Samples where Sample < 10 ) then 1 else 0 end;
declare @NewSample as Int, @OldSample as Int;

-- Loop through updating one row at a time.
while @RowCount > 0
  begin
  update Ph
    set @OldSample = Sample, @NewSample = Sample *= 2
    from ( select top 1 Sample from @Samples where Sample < 10 order by Sample ) as Ph
  set @RowCount = @@RowCount;
  -- Do what you will without losing the count of rows updated.
  select @RowCount as 'RowsProcessed', @OldSample as 'OldSample', @NewSample as 'NewSample'
  end
```